# Auto-flow process using linked process?

Tags: ibm-bpm

I need auto flow of process in IBM BPM 8.5.5 version.

How Can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Let me explain step by step

First you need check **Automatically flow to next task** on the first process's Activity. It's located in **Implementation** tab

[image]

```
Second you need do following in the 2nd process's activity
```

1. Assign to Team
2. Choose your Team
3. Choose User Distribution=> Load Balance
4. Filter the team to one user.

   And then Load Balance will automatically assign to the user and autoflow will works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are however certain limitations to that. If you perform a system task with a system user between the activites it wont work for example. With the usage of team services you should be able to circumvent this perticular issue however. Ill provide a list of the exceptions where it wont work.

- When the second task in the sequence is a system task.
- When an intermediate timer event, intermediate message event, or intermediate content event follows the first activity in the sequence.
- When the first activity flows to multiple tasks assigned to the same user, for example in a multi-instance loop or a parallel (split) gateway.
- If the task is being tested in the Process Inspector.
- If the elapsed time between the end of the first task and the arrival of the token at the next task is greater than the autoflow-timeout setting. By default, the autoflow-timeout is set to 3 seconds.

You can use the 100custom.xml file to modify the value of the autoflow-timeout setting.